# Scroll html page to specific tag and stay in focus even though dynamic content is being added in the page

Tags: html, css, ajax, scroll, anchor

I have a page that dynamically inserts pictures in the form of an `<img>` tag into a `<div>`, the page contains several of those `<div>`. The `<h1>` text just above each `<div>` has a specific id, such that when I use that id in an anchor tag, the page will scroll down to show the `<h1>` and `<div>` container. The problem is when accessing the page from another one, for example when opening [this link](http://piyoevents.com/projects/#office). Since the ajax code takes a few seconds to fetch the images and as such resize the height of the several `<div>` containers, the page scrolls down to the tag with id "office" before the images have the time to be inserted. The container which I was trying to scroll to get lost as the other `<div>` containers' height change.

Is there a way of making the browser stay in focus with the `<div>`, and scroll up and down according to the dynamic change in the page? And maybe break the focus when the user clicks or scrolls manually?

Thanks.

Comment: I would check if the URL has a hash, if so, I would set the location again (within a callback) after ajax finished loading the images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best option would be to fix the height of the divs containing the images so that the page will always be a certain height.
Then when it scrolls down it won't be out of position when the images load.

You could also check with javascript to see if there is a # in the url, and then prevent the jump until the page has fully loaded.

check the hash with

```
if (location.hash) {
    //prevent scroll
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);

    //add function to wait till page fully loaded then scroll to anchor
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I fixed the height of the divs in css, it was good enough. Can't believe I didn't think of that.